# Norm convergence plus continuity imply pointwise convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, measurable-functions, pointwise-convergence

I recently noticed a lemma in this paper:

Wanner, Thomas. "Linearization of random dynamical systems" Dynamics reported. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 1995. 203-268.
[image]

The statement in the brackets causes me confusion. Does it mean the continuity of $\nu_n(\cdot, p)$ and $\|\cdot\|_p$-convergence of $\nu_n(\cdot, p)$ imply the poinwise convergence of $\nu_n(a, p)$? This seems not quite right since norm $\|\cdot\|_p$ is not specified.

Any hint or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: For fixed $p$ you have $\nu_n(\cdot,p)\to\nu^*(\cdot,p)$ in $B_p$. It is assumed that for any $a$ the evaluation mapping $B_p\ni\nu\mapsto\nu(a)$ is continuous. Hence, $\nu_n(a,p)\to\nu^*(a,p)$ for all $a$.

Comment: @jakobdt Thank you! I get it now. I mixed these two concepts up, the continuity of evaluation mapping $\nu\rightarrow\nu(a)$ and the continuity of $a\rightarrow\nu(a)$.